# I can't get parameter from url in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I know there are enough similar topics, but I can't get the parameter from the url.
Help me figure it out. What am I doing wrong?
Here is an example of my code:

```
<api context="/auth" name="AuthHarv" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/harv/token={tokenVal}">
    <inSequence>
        <log separator="&#xa;">
            <property expression="$url:uri.var.tokenVal" name="token1"/>
            <property expression="$url:uri.var.token" name="token2"/>
            <property expression="$url:tokenVal" name="token3"/>
            <property expression="$url:token" name="token4"/>
            <property expression="$url:uri.var.tokenVal" name="uri.var.token1"/>
            <property expression="$url:uri.var.token" name="uri.var.token2"/>
            <property expression="$url:tokenVal" name="uri.var.token3"/>
            <property expression="$url:token" name="uri.var.token4"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.tokenVal')" name="getToken1"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.token')" name="getToken2"/>
            <property expression="get-property('tokenVal')" name="getToken3"/>
            <property expression="get-property('token')" name="getToken4"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.tokenVal')" name="uri.var.getToken1"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.token')" name="uri.var.getToken2"/>
            <property expression="get-property('tokenVal')" name="uri.var.getToken3"/>
            <property expression="get-property('token')" name="uri.var.getToken4"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.tokenVal')" name="paramToken1"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.token')" name="paramToken2"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.tokenVal')" name="uri.var.paramToken1"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.token')" name="uri.var.paramToken2"/>
        </log>
        
        <property expression="concat('https://localhost:44343/Account/login?token=', $ctx:token)" name="uri.var.url" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log separator="&#xa;">
            <property expression="$ctx:uri.var.url" name="path to harvest"/>
        </log>
        <call>
            <endpoint>
                <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.url}">
                    <suspendOnFailure>
                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                    </suspendOnFailure>
                    <markForSuspension>
                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    </markForSuspension>
                </http>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <log separator="&#xa;">
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="JSON_auth_from_harvest"/>
        </log>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

This is what I get in the log:

Direction: request
token1 = 
token2 = 
token3 = 
token4 = 
uri.var.token1 = 
uri.var.token2 = 
uri.var.token3 = 
uri.var.token4 = 
getToken1 = token_value 
getToken2 = null
getToken3 = null
getToken4 = null
uri.var.getToken1 = token_value
uri.var.getToken2 = null
uri.var.getToken3 = null
uri.var.getToken4 = null
paramToken1 = null
paramToken2 = null
uri.var.paramToken1 = null
uri.var.paramToken2 = null
[2022-04-13 19:34:05,164]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:AuthHarvest} To: /auth/harv/token=token_value

Why can't I get the value from $url:prop?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `uri template` not entirely correctly with REST. It should be something like:
`uri-template="/harv?token={tokenValue}"` (with question mark).
And then You can get the parameter value using:

```
<property name="token" expression="get-property('query.param.token')"/>
```

or

```
<property name="tokenVal" expression="get-property('uri.var.tokenVal')"/>
```

And as I see, even in your template, you get the value:
`getToken1 = token_value` and `uri.var.getToken1 = token_value`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. it helped me, I got data in params `token4`, `uri.var.token4`, `getToken1`, `uri.var.getToken1`, `paramToken2` and `uri.var.paramToken2`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with how you defined your uri-template (`uri-template="/harv/token={tokenVal}"`).

**Path parameter**

If you want to define a path parameter, it should be.

```
uri-template="/harv/{tokenVal}"
```

You can access it with

```
<property name="pathParam" expression="get-property('uri.var.tokenVal')"></property>
```

**Query parameter**

If the parameter is sent as a query parameter

```
uri-template="/harv?token={tokenVal}"
```

You can access it with

```
<property name="queryParam" expression="get-property('query.param.token')"></property>
<property name="queryParam" expression="$url:token"></property>
```

Refer to documentation [1] to get more information on this.

[1]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rest_api_examples/setting-query-params-outgoing-messages/